# How to count users posts in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

In a simple forum app in Django, on each thread I want to render posts by several users on the same page (on a user panel at the user's post, like all conventional forums).

Here are the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)


class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    published = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


    def num_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.count()

    def num_replies(self):
        return max(0, self.post_set.count() - 1)

    def last_post(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by("-created")[0]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.creator) + " - " + self.title

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have also this wierd model:

```
class PostCount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    posts =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user):
        postcount = cls(user=user)
        return postcount
```

Which somehow magically returns number of topics by a user (not number of posts) so that they can be accessed in the template using `{{topic.creator.postcount.posts}}`.

And the view that render topics:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Listing of posts in a topic."""


    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic_id).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, DJANGO_SIMPLE_FORUM_REPLIES_PER_PAGE)
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)    

    topic.visits += 1
    topic.save()

    forum = topic.forum
    return render_to_response("myforum/topic.html", add_csrf(request, posts=posts, pk=topic_id,
        topic=topic, forum= forum), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So I'm wondering how best to have number of posts by a user in template?

Answer (score 2):

Do you not want to use the built in count, because that would solve your problem.

views.py- should get all the users, if you wanted a selected user group per se you would just use filter

```
 context = {}
 post_numbers =  Post.objects.all().count()
 context['post_numbers'] = post_numbers
```

Template

```
  {{ post_numbers }}
```

Comment: This does not show anything in the template. Also please not that there are several users involved. How does this queryset can capture them all?